# Why ngIf doesn't work with the class property

Tags: javascript, angular

In my Angular application I created a control that shows some data.
I have a "className" class, one of its fields (ShowDetails) is declared Boolean, so if the user clicks on a button I set `ShowDetails = true` and shows a div with information.

```
@Input() className: ClassName;
...
ShowDetails($event){
  this.className.ShowDetails = true;
}
...
<app-details-info *ngIf="className.ShowDetails" (closed)="ClosedDetails($event)" [info]="className">

</app-details-info>
```

Unfortunately it's not working (and it doesn't print any error on console), but if i change

> *ngIf="**className.ShowDetails**"

with a local boolean variable works perfectly fine.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Can you share a stckbiltz

Comment: Where is `className.ShowDetails` declared?

Comment: try `*ngIf="className?.showDetails===true"`

Comment: Why did you get the className from input ?!

Comment: @StepUp 
the class is loaded by an angular service that parse json received from a REST service.

Comment: @Ilia Afzali the angular application is more complex, this is a control who show one of many "className" readed from database

Comment: @MatteoZambon it is better to write your code in your question. Or to get faster your answer, it would be better to create [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) example

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qm4xrr?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

this is the link, but i can't simulate all controls i created, the service an the REST service (i know on stackblitz it works somehow)

Comment: @MatteoZambon have you tried to write `*ngIf="className?.ShowDetails"` with question mark?

Comment: @Stepup yes, but nothing happened, i try debug with chrome, the code correctly enter the method ShowDetails($event), and i see the class with correct value, still nothing happened

Comment: @MatteoZambon it it is methodm then you should write like method name `*ngIf="className?.ShowDetails(foo)"` and `ShowDetails()` method should return `boolean` value.

Comment: Ok i'm an as**ole! the Json returned from REST service is:
...**s**howDetails with lowercase s, but in my code i have declare a class with **S**howDetails with uppercase, so angular doesn't give me any error and instantiate a new class that is not MY class, but has almost the same propriety (thats why everithing else was working)

Answer (score 6):

Try to use `?` operator:

```
<app-details-info *ngIf="className?.ShowDetails">

</app-details-info>
```

`?` is a safe navigation operator in templates. This expression `className?.ShowDetails` is equivalent to `className != null ? className.ShowDetails : null`

Answer (score 2):

the answer of @StepUp totally correct by using `?.` safe navigation operator but another way is to set a default value to `class Name` property like this

`@Input() className: ClassName = new CalssName();`

in this case if `ShowDetails` has not set in the class the value will be `undefined` and the if expression will evaluate as falsy

Answer (score 0):

After a long debug and many tests, I figured out:

The Json returned from REST service was:

```
{
  ...
  showDetails: false,
  ...
}
```

with **lowercase s**, but in my code i have declare a class with

```
ShowDetails : boolean;
```

with **uppercase S**.

Angular (Typescript) does not give me any errors and creates an instance of a new class that is not MY class, but has almost the same property (thats explain why why everything else was working)